# Calculating taxes based on income and wealth input in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where the user can type his income and savings. I want to calculate taxes based on that info and display it on the screen when i click a button. I'm trying to do this using JavaScript, which i'm very new to. Also pretty new to HTML forms.

Here's the pseudocode for the tax calculation itself:

```
tax(income, wealth) = (0.35 * income) + (0.25 * wealth)
```

Here's my attempt on making a this work. I didn't include all the HTML code here, only the last part of the form.

HTML

```
<form>

<label>Income</label>
<input id="income" type="number" name="income" min="0"><br>

<label>Wealth</label>
<input id="wealth" type="number" name="wealth" min="0"><br>

<label>Tax</label><br>
<input id="tax" type="number" name="tax" disabled>

<button type="button" name="button" onclick="calculatetax();"> Calculate 
tax</button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>
```

Javascript

```
function calculatetax() {
  var salary = document.getElementById('income').value;
  var savings = document.getElementById('wealth').value;
  var taxes = (0.35 * salary) + (0.25 * savings);

  var totalTax = document.getElementById('tax')
  totalTax.innerHTML = taxes.value;
}
```

I want to make the tax result appear on the screen when i click the button, and i want it to appear in the "tax" input if that makes sense.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What is the problem you're having?

Comment: There's no error, but nothing happens. The calculation doesn't appear on the page.

Comment: Please read a bit around JS debugging. Use a browser debugger like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger or adding `console.log` statements to check the behavior of the application

Comment: You are getting an error.  Always have your browser's development console open when doing development work.  Errors go to the console.  In most browsers the keyboard shortcut is F12.

Comment: How are you referencing the JS? Since the HTML is using JS, the js block needs to be in the head of the HTML file.

Comment: @HankMoody did you resolve your issue?  If not, try putting a `console.log("Test");` in your JavaScript function.  See if the function is even being called.  This is a quick form of debugging that is useful to see how far your code is executing without using Breakpoints.

Comment: Yeah i did, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd set your `disabled` tax input to `readonly`.  It allows the user to still copy the value unlike your disabled input.

This:

`<button type="button" name="button" onclick="calculatetax();"> Calculate 
tax</button>`

Can be changed to:

`<button type="button" name="button" onclick="calculatetax()"> Calculate 
tax</button>`

You are assigning our JavaScript variable `taxes` to a value.  You don't need to get the value with `.value` instead just do:

`totalTax.innerHTML = taxes;`

Comment: Thanks. Made those changes, but it still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your JS

```
var totalTax = document.getElementById('tax')
totalTax.innerHTML = taxes;
```

taxes is just a variable, it does not have an attribute of `value`

Demo: https://liveweave.com/6X4DKW

https://jsfiddle.net/r1xsv9dm/

Comment: So i have to use var taxes = ((0.35 * salary) + (0.25 * savings)).value instead? I tried that, but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: `value` is an attribute on the HTML elements. The JS var itself is a value, you can inspect it by adding breakpoints on the source.

Comment: Your link to "Demo" at https://liveweave.com/6X4DKW has no javascript code in it, and none of the OP's HTML form fields. What is it supposed to be demonstrating?

Comment: Not sure why liveweave is not rendering for you, same code here at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r1xsv9dm/